# Arial Narrow font displays as Tahoma in Windows CE Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

When I add controls to my Windows CE 6.0 project in visual studio, I can choose one of the following fonts: Arial, Arial Narrow, Tahoma, Times New Roman

However when I lauch the emulator, all the labels that I chose Arial Narrow are displaying in Tahoma.

I don't know if this is a configuration issue with the emulator. If so, I'm not sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Arial isn't in the OS.  Just becasue Visual Studio allows you select a font does not mean that the font itself is available on the device.  If a font isn't available, the OS will "select" the closest match it can to the requested font.  Your best bet would be to either:

A. Get an OS image that does include the font you want ([Arial *is* available in Platform Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-ce-6-os-components.aspx))

or

B. Find [a distributable version of the font](http://ttfonts.net/search.htm?q=arial) and deploy it with your app